# json parse not working

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting this response from my server with ajax call

```
var data = 
[{
     "Response": {
        "ResponseStatus": {
            "Code": "1",
            "Description": "Success"
        },
        "TransactionReference": {}
    }
}, {
    "Response": {
        "ResponseStatus": {
            "Code": "1",
            "Description": "Success"
        },
        "TransactionReference": {}
    }
}];
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
              "type":"POST",
              "url":"'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("packaging/calltag")).'",
              "data":$("#returnrequestcreationform").serialize(),
              "success":function(data){
                  $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                      console.log(key + val);
                  });
              },
 });
```

But in the log, it gives me this

```
0[
1{
2"
3R
4e
5s
6p
7o
8n
```

I have tried JSON.parse() and jQuery.parseJSON() which give me "unexpected end of input" error when trying to read this object. It looks like a proper json return to me? Any idea why it is looping through it as if it is a string?

Comment: I can't help but notice the missing semicolon.  (`var data = ...`)

Comment: I am not using that code, it is just showing what data is being set to. I am using the step through debugger in chrome and what the data variable is getting getting set to is what is within the [] within the success function

Comment: That was more for people pasting your code into a console to test it.

Comment: JSON.stringify converts it into a string with escape characters for the quotes. Wonder if I could convert it back and it work?

Comment: Sorry my bad.  I was getting it mixed up with `JSON.parse()` which you're already using.  Ignore that comment.

Comment: Have you tried changing the dataType attribute as has been suggested below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the function what the data type is

```
$.ajax({
          "type":"POST",
          "url":"'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("packaging/calltag")).'",
          "data":$("#returnrequestcreationform").serialize(),
           "dataType": "json",
          "success":function(data){
              $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                  console.log(key + val);
              });
          },
 });
```

Comment: This works. I thought I tried it already and the problem ended up being that there was extra text in my response because a view was being rendered along with the echo JSON_ENCODE($res);

Answer (score 0):

Use the dataType option for your query ajax call to tell it you expect a json response.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/